# Use matplotlib figures in another matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

So I have a function that takes in entry some data, and return a matplotlib figure. This is what is looks like (as I deal with very specific data inside my function, I can't provide a minimal working example but my question is more about general stuff).

```
 def foo(data):
     fig, ax= plt.subplots()
     ...
     return fig
```

This function works perfectly well, if I want the picture to appear, I just call `foo(data).show()` and everything's fine.

My problem is that I am willing, in another part of the code (not in the same file), to use that figures in a more general figure. For instance, I might have `foo(data1)`, `foo(data2)` and `foo(data3)` that I want to put in a row in the same matplotlib figure.

Actually, I don't know if it is possible to do that in Matplotlib, and how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your `fig` and `ax` outside of the function, and pass `ax` as a parameter with a default value (so we can create the ax in the function to keep backwards compatibility:

```
def foo(data, ax=None):
   if ax is None:
      _, ax = plt.subplots()
```

This allows you to still call `foo(data)` as before.

If you need to plot this "function" multiple times, as requested, then:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3)

foo(data1, axes[0])
foo(data2, axes[1])
foo(data3, axes[2])
```

If `fig` is also required, either pass it as a parameter to the function, or access it through `ax.figure`. Code will become:

```
def foo(data, ax=None):
   if ax is None:
      fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   else:
      fig, ax = ax.figure, ax
```

Comment: In my ``foo`` function I make some calls to ``fig``, I tried your solution but I get the following error: NameError: name 'fig' is not defined, should I pass ``fig`` also as a parameter ?

Comment: Either you pass ``fig`` as a parameter, or you access it from ``ax.figure`` (I think this works ^^)